# System Sound as Input (Web Audio API)

Tags: html, audio, input, system, web-audio-api

Is there any way to take the system's sound as an input for the Web Audio API?

For example take a user's spotify music that is playing as an input and analyze it to do stuff with it?

Comment: That seems like a massive scurity risk, so I want to say definitely not.

Comment: @laif on the client's side? you can also get the microphone sound so I'm not sure how it really differs if you ask for confirmation first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specification which almost does what you want. It's the counterpart of the Media Capture and Streams spec (aka `getUserMedia()`).

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
```

The spec is called [Screen Capture](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share) and as the name implies it is meant for capturing video and not audio. Capturing audio is optional and not yet supported by any browser if I recall correctly.

There is currently an [open issue discussing audio-only support](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-screen-share/issues/100). Maybe it's a good idea to share your use case there.

Comment: Awesome man! Thank you very much, seems like a fun thing to dive into :)